# integrating ccavenue i am getting 10001 error code invalid request encrypted request invalid or not present

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting 1001 error code while integrating cc-avenue using Asp.Net MVC.
It also showing that Encrypted request is invalid/not present.
I am not able to trace this error in cc-avenue error code list.

please help me.

Comment: hey there. there are a lot of reason that could make this happen.. without the exact error message and the code throwing it, it's really hard to answer this. it's unclear what you are really asking

Comment: HI i have same problem. Have you solve your problem if yes then help me out.